# How Do I Avoid np.where Calculating Divisions By Zero?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, division, zero

```
Results = np.where(
    thing_minus_1 == 1,
    0,
    (1 - thing) / (1 - thing_minus_1),
)
```

Running this code causes a warning:

`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide`

This is because it calculates that divide before the `where` is applied, so it's still calculating it for the zero-denominator elements. It evaluates `(1 - thing) / (1 - thing_minus_1)`, then passes the result of that as the third argument to np.where().

The question is: What do I replace this code with to avoid this warning without simply turning off the warning?

I tried using a regular if statement to fix the issue, but forgot that `where` looks at an array of elements. So I’m not certain what to do.

Edit: It seems like this is a good solution (provided with help from the comments):

```
denominator = np.where((1 - thing_minus_1) == 0, 1, (1 - thing_minus_1))
Results = np.where(
    thing_minus_1 == 1,
    0,
    (1 - thing) / denominator,
)
```

Comment: `np.where` wont help as it uses vectorized computation and replacement. consider using `x[condition] = 0; x[not_condition] = computation(x[not_condition])`

Comment: Your 3rd arg is going to be processed before where is even called so, you need something like  `thing / ((1-thing_minus_1) or 1)`

Comment: You got the reason right.  The zero divide occurs before `where` runs.  But `ufunc` like `np.divide` take a `where` (and `out`) parameter  that does what you want.